# How to get last record from Master-Details tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I have a `table` that has 3 `columns`.

```
create table myTable
(
    ID  int Primary key,
    Detail_ID   int references myTable(ID) null, -- reference to self
    Master_Value    varchar(50) -- references to master table
)
```

this table has the follow records:

```
insert into myTable select 100,null,'aaaa'
insert into myTable select 101,100,'aaaa'
insert into myTable select 102,101,'aaaa'
insert into myTable select 103,102,'aaaa' ---> last record

insert into myTable select 200,null,'bbbb'
insert into myTable select 201,200,'bbbb'
insert into myTable select 202,201,'bbbb' ---> last record
```

the records is saved In the form of `relational` with `ID` and `Detail_ID` columns.
I need to select the last record each `Master_Value` column. follow output:

```
lastRecordID    Master_Value    Path

202             bbbb            200=>201=>202
103             aaaa            100=>101=>102=>103
```

**tips:**

1. The records are not listed in order in the table.
2. I can not use the `max(ID)` keyword. beacuse data is not sorted.(may
   be the `id` column updated manually.)

**attempts:**

I was able to Prepare follow query and is working well:

```
with Q as
(
select ID ,Detail_ID, Master_Value , 1 RowOrder, CAST(id as varchar(max)) [Path] from myTable where Detail_ID is null
union all
select R.id,R.Detail_ID , r.Master_Value , (q.RowOrder + 1) RowOrder , (q.[Path]+'=>'+CAST(r.id as varchar(max))) [Path] from myTable R inner join  Q ON Q.ID=R.Detail_ID --where r.Dom_ID_RowType=1010
)

select * into #q from Q 

select Master_Value, MAX(RowOrder) lastRecord into #temp from #Q group by Master_Value

select 
    q.ID lastRecordID, 
    q.Master_Value, 
    q.[Path]
from #temp t
    join #q q on q.RowOrder  = t.lastRecord
where
    q.Master_Value = t.Master_Value
```

but I need to simple way (`one select`) and optimal method.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Regarding the tag "with-statement", it's called a Common Table Expression, or CTE ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses a correlated subquery to get the last value (which is how I interpreted your question):

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where not exists (select 1
                  from mytable t2
                  where t2.master_value = t.master_value and
                        t2.id = t.detail_id
                 );
```

This returns rows that are not referred to by another row.

For the path, you need a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select master_value, id as first_id, id as child_id, convert(varchar(max), id) as path, 1 as lev
      from mytable t
      where detail_id is null
      union all
      select cte.master_value, cte.first_id, t.id, concat(path, '->', t.id), lev + 1
      from cte join
           mytable t
           on t.detail_id = cte.child_id and t.master_value = cte.master_value
      )
select cte.*
from (select cte.*, max(lev) over (partition by master_value) as max_lev
      from cte
     ) cte
where max_lev = lev
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9c943b59556bd629b4324d8cf091f704) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: thanks for the answer @Gordon Linoff. please note the my output.
this query is not my answer.

Comment: @AminRostami . . . I realized after I answered that the "path" is a key part of what you want to get.  I revised the answer.

Comment: where is the `lastRecordID` column?

Comment: This is the point. the `lastRecordID` is a key part. `Path` column is for more info.

Comment: @AminRostami . . . That information is in the recursive CTE; I just didn't surface it.  I fixed the answer.